# JSON Parsing in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, nsurlsession, swift4

I'm quite new to Swift and i am trying to return a string from my parsed JSON array. I'm not sure how i use the "arrayString" var in another class as i haven't "declared" it in the other class. I assume it has something to do with it being in URLSession. Any tips on what i could do?

```
struct Games: Decodable {
let videoLink: String
}
class BroadService: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = BroadService()
func fetchBroadcasts(completion: @escaping ([Games]) -> ()) {
    let jsonUrlString = "LINK IS HERE."
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Games].self, from: data)
            let arrayString = (json[linkcell].videoLink)
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

This is my code at the minute, It's not the most neat thing in the world, but it gets the job done.

Comment: When you say you have issues using this in another class, what do you mean? In most cases, it's going to something wrong with the type, or something to do with implicitly unwrapping an optional. Can you expand on the issue you're having? I assume 'arrayString' is what you want to be returned?

Comment: Yeah, having problems was an awful way of putting it, ill re edit it now. I really mean i don't know how to use this variable in a different class as it tells me i haven't declared it in other classes

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You needlessly extend `NSObject`.
2. You never call the `completion` block.
3. `arrayString` is not an array.
4. Your completion block should at least make the Games array optional to indicate an error.

Here's how your code should be:

```
struct Games: Decodable {
    let videoLink: String
}

class BroadService {
    static let sharedInstance = BroadService()

    func fetchBroadcasts(completion: @escaping ([Games]?) -> ()) {
        let jsonUrlString = "LINK IS HERE."
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            do {
                let games = try JSONDecoder().decode([Games].self, from: data)
                completion(games)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error deserializing json:", jsonErr)
                completion(nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Then you can call it as follows:

```
BroadService.sharedInstance.fetchBroadcasts { (games) in
    if let games = games {
        // Process all games if needed
        for game in games {
            let videoLink = game.videoLink
            // do something
        }

        // Or access a specific game:
        let game = games[someIndex]
        let videoLink = game.videoLink
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that goes a long to cleaning up everything. Is there anyway i can access the "game"/"videoLink" var outside of "BroadService.sharedInstance.fetchBroadcasts { (games) in". Not sure if that's worded correctly. Thanks for all your help

Comment: You must at least access it initially inside as shown in my answer. You can assign `games` (or a specific game from the array) to some more "permanent" storage for access in other code if needed.

Comment: Perfect thanks, Apolgies for the "basic" questions but could you tell me how i'd go about doing that? If not, no worries you've been a massive help